# undefined method 'assign_to' after updating shoulda-matchers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, rubygems, shoulda

I updated `'shoulda-matchers'` in the Gemfile in my rails project from version 1.4.2 to 2.0.0 and now when I run my rspec tests, it is giving me the following error

```
undefined method `assign_to' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_4::Nested_1::Nested_4::Nested_1:0x007fc96eaaaf48>
```

Was this method removed in the new 2.0.0 release?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, the following methods were deprecated in version 1.5.0 and removed in version 2.0.0 of shoulda-matchers.

- `assign_to`
- `respond_with_content_type`
- `query_the_database`
- `validate_format_of`
- `have_sent_email`
- `permit` (strong parameters matcher)
- `delegate_method`

The developers recommend testing the code in another way if you are currently using these methods.

For a brief list of changes you can visit https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/NEWS.md#v-200.

For a more detailed list of changes and reasons to why these methods were removed you can visit their blog http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/47031676783/shoulda-matchers-2-0.